# sitemap.xml file extension, does it have to be .xml?

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap, xml, filenames

Do XML sitemap files have to end with the `.xml` file extension?

On the Bigcommerce platform, their XML sitemap file are defined as:

```
http://www.examplesite.com/xmlsitemap.php
```

The sitemap file is all correctly marked up and and when saving locally its saves as an `.xml` file. I've also seen some Joomla sitemap plugins create sitemaps with `.php` extensions.

The [Sitemap Protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/) site doesn't cover this.

I unfortunately don't have access to GWT too see if it verifies.

Comment: Don't forget to approve an answer if you like it, thanks!

Comment: Use an HTTP router like https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute and create a route that matches "/sitemap\.xml", then you render a xml response.

Answer (score 4):

**It has been verified that a PHP file can be used as a sitemap file such as sitemap.php**

1. I checked *http://sitemaps.org* (the website with the specification information for sitemaps) and there is no mention that the file must be saved in the .XML format. I will have to say that yes, it will work, as long as Google does not have a problem with the extension for some reason.
2. When you go through Google Webmasters Tools and click on submit/test a sitemap you are prompted with your site's root directory `http://example.com/` immediately followed by a text field you can enter any file name and extension into; with no file extension forcing you to use an actual "XML" file here I'm assuming that you can use a sitemap with a .PHP extension.

Comment: I can confirm that works, I had to a dynamic sitemap once and ended up writing a php script to generate the xml. Have tried this with GWT and BWT both.

Comment: But does it need to be served with an XML mime type i.e. text/xml?

Answer (score 1):

I gzip my sitemap to `mymap.xml.gz` and it works fine when I declare it so in my `robots.txt`.  If you have a Google Webmaster Tools (GWT) account, GWT will tell you if there is any issue with your sitemap.

So, no, the extension does not have to be `.xml`.